# wordpress how to access error messages in login form

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I want to use my custom login form in wordpress. I want to show in my form the wordpress login error messages too but i don't know how to do this.

I have creaded the div class="log-msg" to output the login error messages.

Here my code:

my-custom-login.php

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="log" class="form-control" id="user-login" required>
                              <label for="user-login">Login</label>
<input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="form-control" required>
                                <label for="user_pass">Password</label>

<?php
// Here how can i access to error login messages? //

echo '<div class="log-msg">'.$error.'</div>';
                    ?>
?>
<button type="submit" name="btn-submit" id="btn-submit">
</form>
```

I've tried with

```
global $errors;
    $err_codes = $errors->get_error_codes();
```

But it didn't works :S

Someone could help me please?

Thank you everybody!